# Filtering Dictionary with List of Lists as Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary with values being a list of lists, e.g.:

```
Review_dict["0002"]

[['0002', '0292', '4', datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 27, 11, 1, 34)],
 ['0002', '0251', '5', datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 27, 12, 2, 24)],
 ['0002', '0050', '5', datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 27, 12, 3, 24)],
 ['0002', '0314', '1', datetime.datetime(1998, 3, 4, 10, 5, 45)]]
```

I want to remove certain list (within the "big" list), where 2nd element = '0251' or '0314'.

e.g. Review_dict["0002"] should become:

```
[['0002', '0292', '4', datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 27, 11, 1, 34)],
 ['0002', '0050', '5', datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 27, 12, 3, 24)]]
```

I have come up with this code but I want to know if there's a simpler/ more elegant way to do so.

```
remove = ['0251', '0314']

for key in list(Review_dict):
    for ID in remove:
        for num in range(len(Review_dict[key])):
            if Review_dict[key][num][1] == ID:
                del Review_dict[key][num]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just mutate the values of your outer dict:

```
remove = ['0251', '0314']

for v in Review_dict.values():
    v[:] = (lst for lst in v if lst[1] not in remove)
```

Generally, one should not repeatedly remove from a list as each remove has linear complexity. Building from scratch is the better option. Whether this performs better depends on your data and how much there actually is to remove.

As a mutation, the slice assignment `v[:] = ...` allows to ignore the keys of the outer dict entirely as you don't need to rebind them.

Comment: Elegant and efficient. Thumb up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension as:

```
import datetime
Review_dict = dict()

Review_dict["0002"] = [['0002', '0292', '4', datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 27, 11, 1, 34)],
 ['0002', '0251', '5', datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 27, 12, 2, 24)],
 ['0002', '0050', '5', datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 27, 12, 3, 24)],
 ['0002', '0314', '1', datetime.datetime(1998, 3, 4, 10, 5, 45)]]

print(Review_dict)
Review_dict["0002"] = [l for l in Review_dict["0002"] if l[1] not in ['0251', '0314']]
print(Review_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'0002': [['0002', '0292', '4', datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 27, 11, 1, 34)], ['0002', '0050', '5', datetime.datetime(1998, 2, 27, 12, 3, 24)]]}
```

Here you only take elements which satisfy the criteria i.e. first element of inner list is not present in some other list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filter-in-python/) and pass a lambda function

```
Review_dict["0002"] = list(filter(lambda x:x[1] not in remove,Review_dict["0002"]))
```